# How to install inltk in virtual environment using pipenv?

Tags: python, pip, nlp, pipenv, virtual-environment

When I try to install inltk package using

```
`pip install torch==1.4.0+cpu torchvision==0.5.0+cpu -f https://download.pytorch.org/whl/torch_stable.html`
```

it runs but when i try using pipenv it doesnot runs.

When i run

```
`pipenv install torch==1.4.0+cpu torchvision==0.5.0+cpu -f https://download.pytorch.org/whl/torch_stable.html`
```

it does not runs and throw error saying -f parsing error.

What should I do to run the pip command using pipenv so that the dependencies are installed on my virtual environment and not on the system.

Thank you and sorry for any grammatical mistakes.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpipenv%5D+%5Bpip%5D+%22-f%22

Answer (score 1):

try to use

```
pip install http://download.pytorch.org/whl/cpu/torch-1.0.0-cp36-cp36m-linux_x86_64.whl
pip install inltk
```

As iNLTK runs on CPU, as is the desired behavior for most of the Deep Learning models in production. inltk is currently supported only on Linux with Python >= 3.6 and it does not have cuda support.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I wanted to run the above command using pipenv is that possible. I just want inltk to be installed on my virtual environment using pipenv. Is that possible?